# QGIS Delete holes "Remove holes with an area less than" is not working

Tags: qgis, area, holes

In QGIS, both Windows 7 and Ubuntu, older and latest versions, I have used r.to.vect to create a GPKG polygon layer. When I try to delete holes below a certain value, all the holes are deleted, even the big ones.

If I convert the GPKG to SHP, hole deletion is perfect. If I convert the SHP back to GPKG, delete holes works perfectly.

I have tried lots of fix tools to the original GPKG, added geometry info, copied and pasted to a multipolygon layer, made sure it is not multipart, and even deleted all the fields and saved again, to no avail.

I can see no property of the original and converted GPKGs that would explain the difference.

Comment: I guess chances for an answer are higher if you share your data, at least a sample of it. At least, you should provide a bit more information. As of now, we don't see what exactly you have and where something could go wrong.

Comment: Did you change the projection?

Comment: Have you tried Fix geometries and then remove holes?

Comment: Is your initial data 3d then gets converted to 2d when you go to shape?  If that is happening that would be mostly compatible with what you have observed.